# Legacy System: Is there some possible database connection leak with this code?

Tags: c#, .net, enterprise-library

We have this legacy system that uses the Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary library from Microsoft:

One method looks like this:

```
  try
    {   
        IDataReader dr = DB.ExecuteReader(storedProcedureName, param1, param2);

        try
        {
            dr.Read();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        finally 
        {
            try
            {
                dr.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }              
    }          
    catch (Exception ex2)
    {
    }
```

The library documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/bb748704(v=pandp.50)

states "Executes the command and returns an IDataReader through which the result can be read. **It is the responsibility of the caller to close the reader when finished**."

should the line:

```
IDataReader dr = DB.ExecuteReader(storedProcedureName, param1, param2);
```

have been included inside the second try? and the first try be removed? Can this generate some leaks? Why?

Answer (score 1):

While cumbersome, this code should not create memory leaks from the data reader.

However, it can be written much simpler and shorter, like this:

```
try
{
    using(var dr = DB.ExecuteReader(storedProcedureName, param1, param2))
    {
        dr.Read(); 
        // It should be probably be while(dr.Read()) { /* do something with the data */ }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
// Do something with the exception!
}
```

Comment: So, there's no problem if the initialization is left outside the try?

Comment: No, there is no problem, since if the `DB.ExecuteReader` throws an exception, the  `IDataReader` does not get initialized.

Answer (score 0):

> Your Code doesn't have any Leaks

But According to this Official [Microsoft docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.close(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
SqlDataReader.Close()
```

Does not throw any Exceptions so you can get rid of inner try catch like this

```
try
{   
    IDataReader dr = DB.ExecuteReader(storedProcedureName, param1, param2);

    try
    {
        dr.Read();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
    finally 
    {
        dr.Close();
    }              
}          
catch (Exception ex2)
{
}
```

But Efficient way of doing this would be to use **Using**  like this

```
try
{
    using(var dr = DB.ExecuteReader(storedProcedureName, param1, param2))
    {
        dr.Read(); 
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```